# How can I use startDate and endDate from dataframe and use it to filter another dataframe in pyspark

Tags: python, pyspark

I have two tables like the following:
First Table:

```
+---+------+----------+----------+
| id|sub_id| startDate|   endDate|
+---+------+----------+----------+
|  2|     a|2018-11-15|2018-12-01|
|  2|     b|2018-10-15|2018-11-01|
|  3|     a|2018-09-15|2018-10-01|
+---+------+----------+----------+
```

Second Table:

```
+---+----------+----+
| id|      date|time|
+---+----------+----+
|  2|2018-10-15|1200|
|  2|2018-10-16|1200|
|  2|2018-10-18|1200|
|  3|2018-09-28|1200|
|  3|2018-09-29|1200|
+---+----------+----+
```

For a particular id and a given startDate and endDate, I require to filter the second table between the given timeframe.

From the filtered table I require the sum of the time column and output should be like following:

```
+---+------+----------+----------+---------+
| id|sub_id| startDate|   endDate|totalTime|
+---+------+----------+----------+---------+
|  2|     a|2018-11-15|2018-12-01|        0|
|  2|     b|2018-10-15|2018-11-01|     3600|
|  3|     a|2018-09-15|2018-10-01|     2400|
+---+------+----------+----------+---------+
```

My objective is to avoid using for loop along with filter. I tried using pandas_udf but it works with only one dataframe.

Comment: You can join both dataframe on id and then filter out the required records. Perform a groupBy after it. However I have one doubt can one id have multiple start and end date as shown in  First Table ?

Comment: Yes, one id can have multiple start date and end date. That is why I was unable to use join.

Comment: can the same id have overlapping periods? e.g. (id, start_date, end_date) = [(2, 2019-10-01, 2019-10-20), (2, 2019-10-05, 2019-10-25)]?

Comment: @ShivanshuPande so can we consider if there are multiple row for one id like in this case for id 2, min start date and max end date as time frame. For id 2: (2018-10-15 to 2018-12-01)

Comment: @ksgj1 Yes it can have overlapping periods

Comment: @Sagar No we cannot, sorry I was not able to reproduce the problem correctly. Please consider another column in first table with 'sub_id' having different values for each id. Now we have to calculate total time for each 'sub_id' from start date to end date.